# Reading on externally modified file

Tags: python, file

I had a small python script which was feed from the stdin. In this sense, the input was generated by a tail -F and then piped to the script. I wanted to avoid using the tail -F and directly read the file from python. This was working fine, following the recipes from http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/follow.py.

So, in the end I have a small function that is as follows:

```
def read_file(thefile, follow_file = True, wait_time = 0.1, seek_end=False):
    if seek_end:
        thefile.seek(0, 2)
    while True:
        line = thefile.readline()
        if not line:
            if follow_file:
                time.sleep(wait_time)
                continue
            else:
                break
        yield line
```

This works fine and in the same way than tail -f. But the reason is was using tail -F before is that sometimes the input file (which is a soft link to the real file) may change and point to a new file. The previous code will not raise any exception in this case and I haven't found any attribute from the file object that allows me to find out that this happened.

Is there something I'm missing or do I need to use pyinotify to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: maybe you could open & close the file, noting the current offset beforehand and seeking after reopening the possibly different file.

Comment: I see two drawbacks in doing so: First, I will need to store also the last entry to detect if it is a different file or still the same. Second, I could do this when there is no new line, but still it will add some large overhead and for my application the latency is important. Anycase, thanks for the suggestion but in this case for the time being I will stick with the tail -F and reading from stdin.